# How to have a function that takes a parameter that is to a function using a function signature in Rust?

Tags: rust

```
fn test<T>(fn(T) -> T, y: T) -> T {
    return test(fn(T) -> T, fn(y));
}
```

Hello, I have a function here in rust that needs to take in the function signature fn(T) -> T as the first parameter, and y of type T. This is a generic function. How do I allow this function to take in that parameter? I keep getting the:

```
expected identifier, found keyword `fn`
```

error.

Thanks.

I tried to add a r# to escape the identitifer but that didnt work.

Comment: You need to pass some function in, not a type.

Comment: What does it mean to ‘take in the function signature’?

Comment: Please explain what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: have the first parameter take in another function as parameter. For instance, to call this function, I would want to do test(addfunction, y) and add function is a seperate function that adds some numbers together. @PitaJ

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways, depending on what you mean by "function". The closest to what you have right now is this.

```
fn test<T>(my_function: fn(T) -> T, y: T) -> T {
    ...
}
```

Like any argument, an argument which happens to be a function must be given a name. This function can be called with a function pointer as its first argument. That is, if you define a function at the top-level of a module *or* a trivial closure (one that doesn't actually close around variables), then you can use it to call `test`. However, you cannot use nontrivial closures. If you want to do so, you need to use one of three closure traits.

`FnOnce` is the strongest closure trait. An `FnOnce` takes its closure values by *value* and can be called once. When it's done, it drops the things it closed over by value. Essentially, `FnOnce` can be thought of as having this signature (an approximation since Rust doesn't have variadic generics):

```
trait FnOnce<Args...> {
  fn call(self, Args...);
}
```

`FnMut` is the next strongest. It can handle mutable closure values by reference and can modify its values. As such, it cannot be called multiple times concurrently (like a `&mut`, we can only have one active reference to its `self` at a time). It can be thought of like so.

```
trait FnMut<Args...> {
  fn call(&mut self, Args...);
}
```

Finally, `Fn` can be called from anywhere, any number of times, and any number of times concurrently. It cannot modify its closure values. Its signature is basically

```
trait Fn<Args...> {
  fn call(&self, Args...);
}
```

Note that in these examples, the only difference is the type of `self`. `FnOnce` has `self` by value, `FnMut` takes `&mut self`, and `Fn` takes `&self`.

To use each of these, your signature would look like one of the following

```
fn test<T, F: FnOnce(T) -> T>(my_function: F, y: T) -> T { ... }
fn test<T, F: FnMut(T) -> T>(my_function: F, y: T) -> T { ... }
fn test<T, F: Fn(T) -> T>(my_function: F, y: T) -> T { ... }
```

So which one should we use? You have four options: The `fn` concrete type or one of the three traits `FnOnce`, `FnMut`, or `Fn`. The traits are hierarchical in nature. Every `Fn` is an `FnMut`, and every `Fn` is an `FnOnce`. Additionally, every function pointer `fn` is a `Fn`, since the empty closure can never be modified and hence we should never need mutable state inside it. So, to summarize,

- `FnOnce` is an incredibly powerful guarantee. Use it if you can. If you're only calling the function once, use this one.
- `FnMut` can be called concurrently. If you're *not* using the function across multiple threads and are *not* calling the function in a way that may be recursive (may call itself as part of its own execution), then use `FnMut`.
- `Fn` is the weakest trait in terms of guarantees. Use this one if you can't use either of the above.
- `fn` restricts you to actual function pointers, not closures. This should be used if you're writing a C-style interface or need FFI compatibility, since C doesn't understand Rust closures.